# Flutter provider and notifyListeners, value doesn't update in ui

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-provider

I have a class :

```
class ProgressStream with ChangeNotifier {
  double? progress;
  getProgress(_uploadTask) {
    return _uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
      progress =
          event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble();
      print(progress);
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

with a provider in main :

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => UserProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ProgressStream(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp())
```

And the widget :

```
Text(context.watch<ProgressStream>().progress.toString())
```

The value of progress doesn't update when it changes.
The widget can read the progress variable but it doesn't update when i call `notifyListeners()`;

Comment: why arent you using [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider` if your data source is a `Stream`? the docs say: *"Listens to a Stream and exposes its content to child and descendants. Its main use-case is to provide to a large number of a widget the content of a Stream, without caring about reacting to events. A typical example would be to expose the battery level, or a Firebase query."*

Comment: I have no clue how to use streamProvider i tried a lot of things but no success